# What happens when we return with a Sum in C++?

Tags: c++

```
int sum(int k) {
  if (k > 0) {
    return k + sum(k - 1);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

int main() {
  int result = sum(10);
  cout << result;
  return 0;
}
```

It's a **C++** code
I don't understand, when you return in the 3rd like (return k + sum(k-1);
aren't we returning
10 + 9 together?
Not like 10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1=55 (Original Output)

shouldn't this be the output?
by this I mean like the return is something like 10+9 then again 9+8 again 8+7
So the output might be like
10+9+9+8+8+7+7+6+6+5+5+4+4+3+3+2+2+1+1+0+0? (ac to me the sum would be like this)
The output would be one hundred?

I know I am wrong but please clear this for me.

Comment: You could try stepping through the code with a debugger and see for yourself.

Comment: You could instead try `int result = sum(3);` and debug by stepping through the code line by line looking at the 1 variable and the flow after each step.

Comment: Except as an exercise, you should never use recursion for O(n) algorithm, just use a loop (safer, faster, less code).

Comment: @Quimby Yeah, I know but I was new that time, and I am still learning how to use a debugger, although I know how to use one, but to set it  up with VSCode is a headache for me at least for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This summation function is using recursion (basically when a function contains a callback of itself inside).

When you call `sum(10)`, the value you will get is `10 + sum(9)`, not just `10 + 9`. Then `sum(9) == 9 + sum(8)` and so on until `sum(10) == 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + sum(0)` which will break the recursion and will just return a constant `0`, and the function will finally return `55`.

There won't be any repeating results as `sum(k - 1)` does not contain `k` in its sum.

Answer (score 6):

The Sum function is equal to `f(n) = n + f(n - 1)` on math statements.

`f(10) = 10 + f(9) = 10 + 9 + f(8) = ... = 10 + 9 + 8 + ... + f(1) = 10 + 9 + 8 + ... + 1 + f(0)`

And,

`f(0) = 0`

So,

`f(10) = 10 + 9 + 8 + ... + 1 + 0`

Answer (score 5):

You can see what actually happens by using a debugger. Or by adding console output to the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int sum(int k) {
  if (k > 0) {
    auto sk = sum(k-1);
    std::cout << "sum(" << k << ") return " << k << " + " << sk << "\n";
    return k + sk;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

int main() {
  int result = sum(10);
  std::cout << result;
}
```

Output is:

```
sum(1) return 1 + 0
sum(2) return 2 + 1
sum(3) return 3 + 3
sum(4) return 4 + 6
sum(5) return 5 + 10
sum(6) return 6 + 15
sum(7) return 7 + 21
sum(8) return 8 + 28
sum(9) return 9 + 36
sum(10) return 10 + 45
55
```

`sum(10)` returns `10 + sum(9)`. It does not return `10 + 9`. And `sum(9)` returns `9 + sum(8)` ... and so on... and `sum(1)` returns `1 + sum(0)` which is `1`.

`sum(k-1)` call the function just like `sum(10)` calls it in main. Recursion often causes confusion, but it is not much different from calling an ordinary function (that might call others functions, including itself).

Comment: can you tell me how to do the console output?

Comment: I mean for every iteration i.e

Comment: @Nilesh sry I dont understand what you mean. The code in the answer does produce output for every step of the recursion

Answer (score 4):

It works exactly like these non-recursive functions, because recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions.

```
int sum_0() {return 0;}
int sum_1() {return 1 + sum_0();}
int sum_2() {return 2 + sum_1();}
int sum_3() {return 3 + sum_2();}
int sum_4() {return 4 + sum_3();}
int sum_5() {return 5 + sum_4();}
int sum_6() {return 6 + sum_5();}
int sum_7() {return 7 + sum_6();}
int sum_8() {return 8 + sum_7();}
int sum_9() {return 9 + sum_8();}
int sum_10() {return 10 + sum_9();}

int main() { cout << sum_10(); }
```